# How can i use main-menu items as a fields in selectbox in drupal 7

Tags: routes, nodes

Helllo,
I have a content type called "Lookbook" in that i want to put one field like "Lookbook For" and this field content select box and main-menu items. I have main-menu list but I want only display submenu items of lookbook menu in select box.
Is it possible that menu links display as fields??
Thanxs..

Comment: what do you want to achieve by putting menu in content type creation form ? and where do you want this form on content creation form or on node view page

Comment: i want this form on content creation form. and i have a views for display pages. and i have apply contextual filter as per menu link. so user can click on menu link form menu it will display specific content for that menu.

Answer (score -1):

First, create a view that references the nodes you want - e.g. that have a parent item with node id x (or whatever the criteria is for those nodes). Get that view right, and the rest is easy.

Upload and enable either the references, or the entity reference module http://drupal.org/project/entityreference or http://drupal.org/project/references

In your content type, choose a node reference item and select widget. You can base the option list on your view.

Comment: Hello gillarf, welcome to DA! I feel rude for down-voting your very first answer, but this answer doesn't seem to have _anything_ to do with the actual question?

Comment: Thanxs gillarf for giving your answer here but this is not related to my question.

Comment: Actually I think gillarf is trying to answer the OP's request. Because he wants to pre-populate the the list widgets available options with a menu.

Comment: no problem Letharion and Gandhi Pranav. I must have misread this question then. I read **'I want only display submenu items of lookbook menu in select box'** and thought the above provided this answer. I still think it does in fact - it depends what menu items you are selecting. Are they nodes?